# Simple code design question

Tags: java

I have a 3 layer app. The second layer is receiving and object from the 3rd layer and there are two attributes from this object that I need to pass on to the 1st  layer (UI). Should I make this object's class visible in the 1st layer (by importing it's package/namespace, which I'm trying to avoid) or should I pass on these attributes as an string array (I'd rather have an Object array, but they're a string and an int types in Java 1.4) and cast them to their proper types in compilation time (Their types are fixed, so thankfully this is an option)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no java expert, but I can offer some general advice from a .NET perspective.  Since that's your background it should be relevant to you.

> Should I make this object's class
>   visible in the 1st layer (by importing it's package/namespace, which I'm trying to avoid

Its OK to import the namespace.  While it may feel like you decrease coupling, this is better than a string array as it does not require expensive [boxing](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=197).

Do not forget that readability is always a serious consideration.  I recommend you take a look at the MVC pattern.

Comment: That was my first choice (as a .NET developer, as yourself put it)... I'm not really into Java's inner workings yet so I figure I should stick with that.

Answer (score 2):

That's what DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) are for. So in short: use Objects in your top-level interface.

Comment: That would be my first choice. But I'm kinda new to Java (specially working with 1.4, which lacks of A LOT of things) and since one of these attributes is an int (primitive type), Java doesn't allow me to cast it to Object (opposed to C#) and I really think it's unecessary to have an Integer type (which can be cast to Object and back). What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: You won't need to care about primitives. Just create a 
class MyDTO implements Serializable { 
    private int myNumValue; 
    private String myStringValue;

     ... getters/setters 
}

and use it in your Facade-API

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean) are your friend, although you'll probably not profit from reusability/serializabiliy.

JavaBeans are classic DTOs ([Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)), used to pass along information in your program.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of UI do you have? Swing? Then DTOs is probably the way to go. Consider to put the DTO classes in a project of its own, which then can be shared by the client side and the server side.

Comment: Actually it's an embedded app for a MFP (Multifunctional Printer), so I basically use a subset of JVM 1.4 and the UI classes are from the printer manufacturer... I'm pretty tight restraints here...

Comment: But the other 2 layers run on a stand-alone server or in embedded mode? Or in other words: are there remote calls/ are there 2 JVMs involved? If yes, have a look at the DTO pattern.